# Using javascript or jQuery to do something based on URL of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, window.location

I would like to know a function that checks the url of the page, and if it's a certain URL, take further action. I am not particular skilled with regular expressions, nor do I know if they would be the best way to do what I need.

I'd like to check the URL, but if it changes slightly, a basic location check isn't sufficient. If the url ends with /# it is the same page. So I need to check using wildcards or other special characters. Conceptually: **`if url = http://*.domain.com/thingcheckingfor*`** where the asterisks represent wildcards meaning anything can be where they are.

`http://blog.domain.com/page1`

`http://www.domain.com/page1`

`http://www.domain.com/page1/#`

...all need to be accounted for, hence my desire to use regular expressions.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((new RegExp('^http://([^\.]+)\.domain\.com/thingcheckingfor(.*)$').test(url))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Apologies if my question was not clear.